# Will not install on my laptop

Tags: installation, boot, boot-failure

Tried installing it every which way, none of them even get me to choose language screen.  Each method turns the screen black after just a few seconds and then nothing ever happens until I turn the computer off and back on.

Comment: Did you [MD5 test the Ubuntu `.iso` image you downloaded](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)? Also, what is the exact make and model of your laptop? Did you try the desktop CD, the alternate CD, both 32-bit and 64-bit CD's, and Wubi, or do you mean something else when you indicate you've tried all installation methods? Please **edit your question** to provide this information.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it" i assume you mean ubuntu 12.04...

So what is the current operating system that your installing 12.04 over?
Also do you mean turns the screen black after booting from a boot-able usb/cd or something else?

If this is the case, some of the files in the usb/cd that are for installing the OS could be corrupted, this happened to me aswell. you just need to erase everything off them or use a different one and then run the program to make it bootable and put all the files back on like you did in the first place.

hope this helps :)